# Include Carbon Fields via Composer with Mozart

Tags: composer, autoloading

Coen Jacobs' [Mozart](https://github.com/coenjacobs/mozart) is a tool to prevent namespace conflicts in Wordpress themes/plugins which utilize Composer for dependency management. It's similar to [PHP Scoper](https://github.com/humbug/php-scoper) but is described as simpler and Wordpress-oriented.

I have mozart configured as follows:

```
  "extra": {
       "mozart": {
           "dep_namespace": "MZoo\\MyPlugin\\Dependencies\\",
           "dep_directory": "/src/Dependencies/",
           "classmap_directory": "/src/Classes/",
           "classmap_prefix": "MYPREFIX_",
           "packages": [
               "htmlburger/carbon-fields"
           ],
           "delete_vendor_directories": true
       }
   },
```

All of the Carbon Fields files are namespace-prefixed and migrated to `src/Dependencies/Carbon_Fields` *except* the `vendor/htmlburger/carbon-fields/config.php` file, which resides above the `core` directory with all of the plugin classes in it.

I have tried copying that file in a script tag:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
      "cp vendor/htmlburger/carbon-fields/config.php src/Dependencies/Carbon_Fields/",
```

And then adding it to autoload with `psr-4` as a `file`:

```
"files": ["src/Dependencies/Carbon_Fields/config.php"]
```

Which makes Mozart mad:

```
Call to undefined function trailingslashit() in .../vendor/htmlburger/carbon-fields/core/Carbon_Fields.php:229
```

I think the solution might be in overriding Carbon Fields' composer autoloading:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Carbon_Fields\\": "core/"
        }
    },
```

Via Mozart's `override_autoload` configuration option, which is "a dictionary, keyed with the package names, of autoload settings to replace those in the original packages' `composer.json` `autoload` property."

So that's what I'm going to work on after my brain decompresses a little.

If anyone would like to chime in, thank you in advance.

### Update

Still can't seem to get it right.

```
"extra": {
      "mozart": {
          "dep_namespace": "MZoo\\MzMboAccess\\Dependencies\\",
          "dep_directory": "/src/Dependencies/",
          "classmap_directory": "/src/Classes/",
          "classmap_prefix": "MZMBOACCESS_",
          "packages": [
              "htmlburger/carbon-fields"
          ],
          "delete_vendor_directories": false,
          "override_autoload": {
              "htmlburger/carbon-fields": {
                "psr-4": {
                  "Carbon_Fields\\": "core/"
                },
                "files": ["./config.php"]
              }
          }
      }
  },
```

The `override_autoload` configuration above doesn't seem to do anything with the `config.php` file.

What I think I need to end up with is:

```
src/Dependencies/Carbon_Fields
|__config.php
|__core/
|____All of the CF class files.
```

What I'm ending up with is:

```
src/Dependencies/Carbon_Fields
|__All of the CF class files.
```

Tried referencing the entire directory in the `override_autoload` like this:

```
"Carbon_Fields\\": "./"
```

What that does is copy the desired directory structure, but breaks compliance with psr-4 autoloading standard.

Answer (score 1):

So, Mozart doesn't yet support fields autoloading, but there's a fork of it that does (which will perhaps be merged into Mozart master at some point.)

So here's the composer file by which I have been able to manage Carbon Fields (and also Eric Mann's Sessionz and WP Session Manager.):

```
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": [
          "phpcs --extensions=php src *.php"
        ],
    "fix": ["phpcbf --extensions=php src *.php"],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "\"vendor/bin/mozart\" compose"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "\"vendor/bin/mozart\" compose"
    ]
    },
  "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "ericmann/sessionz": "^0.3",
        "ericmann/wp-session-manager": "*",
    "htmlburger/carbon-fields": "*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/brianhenryie/mozart",
      "type": "git"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager",
      "type": "git"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev":{
    "coenjacobs/mozart": "dev-rewrite",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "*"
  },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MZoo\\MzMboAccess\\": "src"
        }
    },
  "extra": {
    "mozart":{
      "dep_namespace": "MZoo\\MzMboAccess\\Dependencies\\",
      "dep_directory": "/src/Mozart/",
      "packages": [
        "htmlburger/carbon-fields",
        "ericmann/wp-session-manager",
        "ericmann/sessionz"
      ],
      "delete_vendor_directories": false,
      "override_autoload": {
        "htmlburger/carbon-fields": {
          "psr-4": {
            "Carbon_Fields\\": "core/"
          },
          "files": [
            "config.php",
            "templates",
            "assets",
            "build"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Than, along with the Composer autoload, I require the Mozart-specific autoload:

```
/**
 * Autoload Classes
 */
$wp_mbo_access_autoload = NS\PLUGIN_NAME_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if ( file_exists( $wp_mbo_access_autoload ) ) {
    include_once $wp_mbo_access_autoload;
}

// Mozart-managed dependencies
$wp_mbo_access_mozart_autoload = NS\PLUGIN_NAME_DIR . '/src/Mozart/autoload.php';
if ( file_exists( $wp_mbo_access_mozart_autoload ) ) {
    include_once $wp_mbo_access_mozart_autoload;
}
```